# Conditional iteration of key,value in DataFrameGroupBy

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a pandas (v 0.12) dataframe `data` in python (2.7). I `groupby()` with respect to the `A` and `B` colmuns in  `data` to form the `groups` object which is of type `<class 'pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy'>`.

I want to loop through and apply a function to the dataframes within `groups` that have more than one row in them. My code is below, here each dataframe is the `value` in the key,value pair:

```
import pandas as pd        
groups = data.groupby(['A','B'])
len(groups)
>> 196320 # too large - will be slow to iterate through all
for key, value in groups:
   if len(value)>1:
      print(value)
```

Since I am only interested in applying the function to values where `len(value)>1`, is it possible to save time by embedding this condition to filter and loop through only the key-value pairs that satisfy this condition. I can do something like below to ascertain the size of each `value` but I am not sure how to marry this aggreagation with the original `groups` object.

```
size_values = data.groupby(['A','B']).agg({'C' : [np.size]})
```

I am hoping the question is clear, please let me know if any clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could assign length of the group back to column and filter by its value:

```
data['count'] = data.groupby(['A','B'],as_index=False)['A'].transform(np.size)
```

After that you could:

```
data[data['count'] > 1].groupby(['A','B']).apply(your_function)
```

Or just skip assignment if it is a one time operation:

```
    data[data.groupby(['A','B'],as_index=False)['A'].transform(np.size) > 1].groupby(['A','B']).apply(your_function)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the first line on its own I think runs longer than my for loop. I did not realise I could use `.apply()` on the DataFrameGroupBy though, so maybe that would speed things up (as compared to my clumsy for loop)

Comment: `.transform` is usually pretty fast and combined with `np.size` it is unlikely it will be slower than your function.

Comment: so it is `.transform(np.size)`, not `.transform('count')`

Comment: Correct, you can use whatever is faster as long it returns a scalar to `transform`.